# No puedo logarme en Facebook en una App UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, facebook-api, windows10

Estoy portando una *App de Windows Phone 8.1* a *UWP*.

La *app 8.1* publicada, inicia sesión en Facebook con `windowsazure.mobileservices`.

En *UWP* estoy tratando de usar *FacebookService* (http://www.uwpcommunitytoolkit.com/en/master/services/Facebook/), pero usando el *ID* que usaba antes, no lo consigo, incluso en la *App* demo del *toolkit*, poniendo ese ID que sigue funcionando con la *App 8.1*, me sale siempre el mismo mensaje, ¿Por qué pasa esto?:

> No has iniciado sesión: No has iniciado sesión. Inicia sesión e
>   inténtalo de nuevo.

Este es mi código:

```
// Initialize service
FacebookService.Instance.Initialize("FacebookAppId", FacebookPermissions.PublishActions);

// Login to Facebook
if (!await FacebookService.Instance.LoginAsync())
{
    return;
}
```

Comment: Saludos Panzer Ihnen, ¿Lograste hacerlo funcionar?

Comment: Me ocurre lo mismo en una App UWP para desktop usando Await clicnt.LoginAsync